# Excluir post através de meta_value Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Quando crio um post no Wordpress, eu determino uma data de expiração através de um plugin chamado Post Expirator. Minha dúvida é saber como posso excluir esses posts da home page, categorias e afins quando eles expiram.

Além disso, gostaria de fazer com que todos os posts expirados fossem exibidos em um determinado ponto do meu site.

Tenho tentado usar as meta_keys e meta_value, mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

```
<?php $args = array(
            'meta_key' => '_expiration-date',
            );
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post() ?>

         <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

   <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Com o código acima eu consigo exibir os posts que adiciono uma data de expiração, independente da data em que ele expira, agora quero saber como eu posso excluí-los num loop comparando a data de sua expiração com a data atual.

Comment: Dúvida sincera, o plugin se chama *Post Expirator* e não expira o post quando se faz uma query? Algum jeito ele tem que ter de fazer a query correta que não mostre os tais posts expirados, não?!

Comment: A opção que ele fornece após expirar é deletar o post, transformá-lo em draft ou mover para alguma categoria. O que desejo é manter os posts na categoria em que foram criados, mas no fundo da página, separado dos posts que não expiraram ou que não possuem data de expiração.

Comment: Ok. É que isso do post virar draft ou trocar categoria não está escrito na pergunta (é legal acrescentar, e é só [edit]). Não sei resolver esse tipo de  problemas e usaria esta *search query* como ponto de partida pra encontrar a solução: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwp-query%5d%20meta_key%20date%20is%3aa

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Uma delas é comparando os `meta_values`, que acredito que seja o que você está fazendo. Eu já sugiro uma aproximação um pouco diferente. Veja que a última versão do Post Expirator permite que, após a expiração, você defina o que acontece com um post, incluindo a adição de uma categoria, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Categoria]

Eu sugiro que você crie a categoria "Expirados", ou equivalente, e assim que um post expirar, ele recebe esta categoria. Isso facilita (e muito) a sua vida na hora de realizar o WP Loop. Basta você pegar o `ID` da Categoria "Expirados" através do seu `slug` (expirados), da seguinte maneira:

```
$id_expirados = get_category_by_slug( 'expirados' );
```

E fazer o loop mais ou menos como você está fazendo

```
$args = (array( 'category__not_in' => $id_expirados );

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

if($query->have_posts()) :
   while($query->have_posts()) : 
       $query->the_post();

       get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

   endwhile;
endif;
```

Isso exclui todos os posts dessa categoria, e mostra todos os outros. Para mostrar *somente* os já expirados, a mudança seria

```
$args = (array( 'category__in' => $id_expirados );
```

Assim, somente os expirados serão mostrados.

Acredito que, usando este plugin, essa é a solução mais inteligente. Se você não quiser lidar com categorias, e escolher fazer consultas diretas aos `meta_values`, as coisas mudam um pouco mais de figura.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Caio. Realmente, criar a categoria expirados foi o que fiz, no entanto eu gostaria de manter a ligação dos posts expirados com as suas respectivas categorias. Com isso, os posts expirados seriam exibidos em suas categorias originais, só que não em destaque, no topo da página de categorias, e sim no fundo, separado dos posts que não tenham sido expirados. Neste caso acho que só com as meta_values mesmo. A separação se daria comparando a data atual com a da expiração, mas realmente não acho uma luz para fazer.

Comment: Isso não é tão dificil de fazer. Vou dar uma olhada aqui e já edito a resposta

Comment: @Rafael, acho que fazendo essa separação por `meta_values` vai lhe trazer exatamente o mesmo resultado. Você vai ter posts expirados e posts não expirados. Adicionar uma categoria em um post não impede que ele seja exibido em páginas de outras categorias, a não ser que você explicitamente declare essa exclusão. Pra exibir os expirados embaixo, mas na mesma página, acho que a solução será fazer 2 loops na mesma página. Um sem os expirados e um com os expirados

Comment: Então Felipe, mas na categoria expirados ficariam todos os posts (misturados), aí não conseguiria separá-los e mostrá-los em suas respectivas categorias.

Answer (score 1):

Essa pergunta é antiga mas vou documentar aqui uma forma de fazer que independe de criar categorias como sugerido na outra resposta. O plugin Post Expirator guarda as datas de expiração no [formato timestamp ('U')](https://github.com/wp-mirrors/post-expirator/blob/master/post-expirator.php#L379), então podemos filtrar somente os posts que tem datas de expiração maiores que a atual usando a action [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/), por exemplo:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_expirados' );

function remove_expirados( $query ) {

    // rodar apenas na home page
    if ( is_front_page() ) {

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_expiration-date', // busca posts com datas de expiração
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC',          // compara numericamente
                'compare' => '>',                // buscando valores maiores
                'value'   => time(),             // que a hora atual
            ),
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
```